# PySpark write to storage in CSV, handle commas in data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am using Databricks to write a dataframe to Azure storage in CSV format. I have 5 columns. Some of the rows contain 5 commas in Value column.

When I write to CSV using this code, it results in 10 columns instead of 5 due to the presence of additional columns in the Value column and I want to avoid that. I have tried these options and none of the work:

```py
# Test 1
raw_df.write.partitionBy("Date").format("csv").option("quoteAll",True).option("nullValue","-").save(storage_path)

# Test 2
raw_df.partitionBy("Date").format("csv").option("quoteMode","ALL").option("nullValue","-").save(storage_path)

# Test 3
raw_df.partitionBy("Date").format("csv").option("nullValue","-").save(storage_path)
```

Comment: Can you try `raw_df.write.partitionBy("Date").csv(storage_path, quoteAll=True, nullValue="-")`?

Comment: Also what do you mean by `it results in 10 columns`? How did you count the number of columns? Could you show a few lines of your output?

Comment: I tried `raw_df.write.partitionBy("Date").format("csv").option("quoteAll",True).option("nullValue","-").save(storage_path)`, All columns are quoted in "", so if column has comma in value still it will be one column